# Display message is Not working for out of stock products

Tags: magento

please visit [link1](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-battle-station-multicolor.html) , you can see there is option to find shipping is available or not for particular zip code : **image1**

[image]

here shipping charges  are working for instock products but not for out-of -stock products.

**Form.phtml**

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/form.phtml

```
<?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?> 
  <li class="item"> 

    <label for="search"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>>
      <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?>
        <em>*</em>
      <?php endif;?>
      <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('') ?>
    </label> 
    <div class="search">
      <input placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" 
        class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" 
        type="text" id="estimate_postcode" 
        name="estimate[postcode]" 
        value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" 
        onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}" />
    </div> 
  </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
  (function($) { 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('#estimate_postcode').keydown(function(e){

        var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
          '.shipping-estimation-form select', 
          '#product_addtocart_form input', 
          '#product_addtocart_form select']); 
        var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
        var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 
        console.log("zipcode onkeypress worked"); 
        if (!e) e = window.event; 
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
        if (keyCode == '13'){ 
          //disable default enter action 
          e.preventDefault(); 
          console.log("Enter button was pressed"); 
          $('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
          $('#shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 

          new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
            parameters: parameters, 
            onComplete: function() { 
              console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
              $('#shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
              $('#shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
              $('#unique_id').hide(); 
              //$('unique_id').hide(); 
              $('estimate_postcode').val()
            } 
          }); 
        }; 
      }); 
    }); 
  }) ( jQuery ); 

  function estimateProductShipping() 
  { 

    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>'; 
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input', 
      '.shipping-estimation-form select', 
      '#product_addtocart_form input', 
      '#product_addtocart_form select']); 

    var validationResult = true; 

    // Check the valid input 
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) { 
      return; 
    } 

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true); 

    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show(); 
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide(); 


    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, { 
      parameters: parameters, 
      onComplete: function() { 
        console.log("ajax updater worked"); 
        $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide(); 
        $('shipping-estimate-results').show(); 
        // $('#unique_id').hide(); 
        $('unique_id').hide(); 
        $('estimate_postcode').val()
      } 
    }); 
  } 

  //]]> 
</script>
```

complete code of the file : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebe868508b2c21e9c032

**result.phtml**

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/webdevlopers/productpageshipping/estimate/result.phtml

```
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate block-shipping-results">
  <div class="block-title">
    <strong><span>
    <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getShiptitle(); ?>
    </span></strong>
  </div>
  <div class="block-content">
    <?php if ($this->getResult()):?>
      <dl>
        <?php foreach ($this->getResult() as $code => $_rates): ?>
          <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
          <dd>
            <ul>
              <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                <li<?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()) echo ' class="error-msg"';?>>
                  <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
                    <?php echo $_rate->getErrorMessage() ?>
                  <?php else: ?>
                    <?php 
                      //  echo $_rate->getMethodTitle() 
                    ?>
                    <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
                    <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>

                    <!-- sat -->

                    <p>
                      <?php echo "Shipping is available";?>
                    </p>

                    <p class="vship1">
                      <?php echo "Selling Price + " . str_replace('.00','',$_excl) . " Delivery ";?>
                    </p>

                    <!-- sat -->

                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                        (<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
                    <?php endif; ?>
                  <?php endif ?>
                </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </dl>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php //echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml(); ?>
      <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getResult(); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app/code/community/webdevolopers/productpageshiping/Block/estimate/ Result.php**

```
<?php

class WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Block_Estimate_Result extends WebDevlopers_ProductPageShipping_Block_Estimate_Abstract
{

    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->getEstimate()->getResult();
    }


    public function hasResult()
    {
        return $this->getResult() !== null;
    }


    public function getCarrierName($code)
    {
        $carrier = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getCarrierInstance($code);
        if ($carrier) {
            return $carrier->getConfigData('title');
        }

        return null;
    }


    public function getShippingPrice($price, $flag)
    {
        return $this->formatPrice(
            $this->helper('tax')->getShippingPrice(
                $price,
                $flag,
                $this->getEstimate()
                    ->getQuote()
                    ->getShippingAddress()
           )
        );
    }


    public function formatPrice($price)
    {
        return $this->getEstimate()
            ->getQuote()
            ->getStore()
            ->convertPrice($price, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what response do you get ?

Comment: "Shipping is not avilable" , this message is configurable from backend.

Comment: Can you debug in Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract ? There will be one function called proccessAdditionalValidation check does it reach there ?

Comment: can you please inform how to check its reaching there or not.

Comment: also one quick question. As you product is out of stock so would you like to allow backorders ?

Comment: no , but client want to show shippping charegs for out-of -stock products also

Comment: Just few minutes I will be right back with the solution let me have a look at you code in github

Comment: which shipping method are u using ?

Comment: we are using custom shipping method : [link](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Shipping-On-Per-Product.html)

Comment: ok so this is some custom shipping method module that you are using. So in that module model file probably Carrier.php there will be one method called collectRates. Can you provide code of that ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mF6t2Y5f - carrier/localdelivery.php file

Comment: i want to inform even for default shipping methods also same problem is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108140/discussion-between-rajatsaurastri-and-profile-101).

Comment: @rajatsaurastri please check when you are free....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the settings in `System > Config > Inventory`

Easiest way to do this is select all products you want to allow to be `backordered`, then select Update attributes from the actions drop down and click submit. then shipping problem will not be problem.

Comment: i set one out -of -stock product for  for "`Allow Qty below 0`" , but still same issue is there.....

Comment: http://prntscr.com/aobykv

http://prntscr.com/aobyhc

[link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-medi-kid-8869.html)